# How to merge panda dataframe based on column?

Tags: python, pandas

What's the pythonic / pandas way of merging multiple panda dataframes? ATM i do it with loops, but it does not feel right:

I have three dataframes with credit runtimes, all of them have an `interest` , `liquidation` and `date` field. The credits have different runtimes (e.g. different rows).

Here's a sample of one credit.

```
        amount      annuity date        int.    int. %  liq.    liq. %  special_payment
0       50,000.00   135.42  2016-09-01  52.08   1.25    83.33   2.00    0
1       49,916.67   135.42  2016-10-01  52.00   1.25    83.42   2.00    0
2       49,833.25   135.42  2016-11-01  51.91   1.25    83.51   2.00    0
3       49,749.74   135.42  2016-12-01  51.82   1.25    83.59   2.00    0
4       49,666.15   135.42  2017-01-01  51.74   1.25    83.68   2.00    0
```

I want to calculate the total burnrate of all credits.

That is:

```
[interest + liquidation of credit 1] +  
[interest + liquidation of credit 2] +  
[interest + liquidation of credit 3]
```

If the credit does not run on that given date, `interest` + `liquidation` should be zero for that.

I'm new to pandas, hence I hope for some insights on how to approach such problem.

Comment: can't you `pd.concat(list_of_dfs, ignore_index=True).fillna(0)`?

Comment: it creates strange results and is not really concatenating things, it mainly reproduces the first df in the list.

Comment: Can you post what your dfs look like and what the desired output df should look like, thanks

Comment: pd.concat([c1, c2], ignore_index=True).fillna(0).head(5) returns http://dpaste.com/12JMQAY (c1 is the credit with the sample above)

Comment: Please post raw text as raw input data, code that loads this data, and what your desired output df should look like, links to images are frowned upon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use concat, but you need to add `axis=1`. I think you need to use the `keys` argument, to be able to distinguish columns with the same names from different credits.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,4),columns=['a','b','c','d'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,4),columns=['a','b','c','d'])
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1,keys=['Credit1','Credit2'])
```

To add numbers from different columns, use, e.g.

```
burnrate = df3['Credit1','a']+df3['Credit2','a']
```

Comment: That works, but how can i align the date column? Some credits start earlier than the others.

Comment: In that case, I think you'll want to use your date column as index. In my example, I can change the index with `df1.index = df1['a']` and likewise for `df2`. For you it would be something like  `credit1.index = credit1['date']`. The best would be to do this immediately when you construct your dataframes.